# How to keep <li> elements fixed top and bottom of <ul> element when scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a `ul` with fixed height, which contian dynamic number of `li` elements, if too many a scrollbar appaers. You can select a `li`element by clicking on it.

What I want is the `li`element that is active to be fixed at the top if scrolling aboveit or fixed at the bottom if scrolling below it, so the active `li` element is always showing, and the other `li` elements just scrolls past the active one.

I have made a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IgES76trE5LrkHgUlFlW?p=preview). I am using Angular, and I dont know if this can be solved just using CSS or if I need a directive etc. for this.

Html:

```
div class="parent">
 <div class="child1">
   <input ng-model="vm.query" type="text" placeholder="Search" />
    <ul  >
        <li ng-repeat="todo in  todos" ng-class="{'active': todo.active}" ng-click="activeTodo($index)">
            <a>{{todo.name}}</a>
        </li>

    </ul>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent{
   display: flex;
}
.child1{

  background-color: #eeeeee;
  height: 500px;
  overflow:scroll;
}
.active{
 background-color: red;
 position:fixed;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not achievable via CSS only. The logic is quite simple, really: on parent scroll check position of active element and determine if it's in view or not. If it's not, change its position to fixed (top or bottom) and (eventually) set a top/bottom padding on the parent. Would you like us to code it for you? If yes, please provide a reason. Preferably a good one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed this using some CSS and making a directive.

Made a plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/os8Bhl0x4O1n13cDAM3a?p=preview).

I made a directive which every `li` element got. Then with jquery in the directive I get the necessary elements like the `div` which have the scroll, the current `li` element etc.

Two booleans for checking if the `li` is fixed at the top or bottom. And then just check if the current scrollPosition(scrollTop) is higher or lower then the current `li` element. And it also check so the `li` element got the active boolean attached too it.

```
return {
        restrict: 'A',

        link: function($scope, element, attributes){

            var scrollDiv = $('#scrollDiv'),
                liElement = element,
                liElementTop = parseInt(liElement.offset().top),
                scrollDivTop = parseInt(scrollDiv.offset().top),
                isFixedTop = false,
                isFixedBottom = false;

            liElement.width(scrollDiv.width());


            scrollDiv.on('scroll', function(){
                var scrollTop = scrollDiv.scrollTop();

                if (!isFixedBottom && !isFixedTop && scrollTop <= liElementTop - (scrollDivTop+(scrollDiv.height()-liElement.height())) && liElement.hasClass("active")) {
                    isFixedBottom = true;
                    liElement.css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': scrollDivTop+(scrollDiv.height()-liElement.height()+1),'list-style-type':'none','z-index':'10'});
                } else if (isFixedBottom && !isFixedTop && scrollTop >= liElementTop - (scrollDivTop+(scrollDiv.height()-liElement.height()))) {
                    isFixedBottom = false;
                    liElement.css({'position': 'static', 'top': 0});
                }
                else if (!isFixedTop && !isFixedBottom && scrollTop >= liElementTop - scrollDivTop && liElement.hasClass("active")) {
                    isFixedTop = true;
                    liElement.css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': scrollDivTop,'list-style-type':'none','z-index':'10'});
                }
                else if (isFixedTop && !isFixedBottom && scrollTop <= liElementTop - scrollDivTop) {
                    isFixedTop = false;
                    liElement.css({'position': 'static', 'top': 0});
                }

            })



        }
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

**The consideration of using pure CSS:** One of the best **solution** is this, because those who perhaps want to make an element remain fixed while it is **scrolling** up and down!

```css
body {
  margin: 10px;
}

ul {
  display: block;
  width: 210px;
  max-height: 120px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  padding: 8px 10px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

li.fixed {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item1</li>
  <li>Item2</li>
  <li>Item3</li>
  <li>Item4</li>
  <li>Item5</li>
  <li>Item6</li>
  <li>Item7</li>
  <li>Item8</li>
  <li>Item9</li>
  <li>Item10</li>
  <li>Item11</li>
  <li>Item12</li>
  <li>Item13</li>
  <li>Item14</li>
  <li>Item15</li>
  <li>Item16</li>
  <li>Item17</li>
  <li>Item18</li>
  <li>Item19</li>
  <li>Item20</li>
  <li>Item21</li>
  <li>Item22</li>
  <li>Item23</li>
  <li>Item24</li>
  <li>Item25</li>
  <li>Item26</li>
  <li>Item27</li>
  <li>Item28</li>
  <li>Item29</li>
  <li>Item30</li>
  <li>Item31</li>
  <li>Item32</li>
  <li>Item33</li>
  <li>Item34</li>
  <li>Item35</li>
  <li>Item36</li>
  <li>Item37</li>
  <li>Item38</li>
  <li>Item39</li>
  <li>Item40</li>
  <li>Item41</li>
  <li>Item42</li>
  <li>Item43</li>
  <li>Item44</li>
  <li>Item45</li>
  <li>Item46</li>
  <li>Item47</li>
  <li>Item48</li>
  <li>Item49</li>
  <li>Item50</li>
  <li class="fixed">HEADER</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you like the active div on top.

to solve this in css

use `position:relative` on parent and `position:absolute` on the child element with `top:0`

Comment: Doing it like this will make the active li always appear on top. Gustav Olsson wants it only on top/bottom when overflown